# Ubuntu 19.10 - Thinkpad X395 Ryzen freezes at login if unplugged

Tags: power-management, thinkpad, 19.10, amd-ryzen

I recently purchased a Thinkpad X395 — AMD® Ryzen 5 pro 3500u w/ radeon vega mobile gfx × 8. I removed Windows and installed Ubuntu 19.10.

Each time I start the laptop whithout the power plugged, the laptop freezes at login (and lags, at the previous step, after my entering the password for encryption). If I then plug it and hard-reboot, everything works fine. If the laptop is plugged at the first place, everything works fine too.

There seems to be some issues with hibernation too as when I close the lid, the laptop can not wake up.

Any hint on the potential issue? (I guess it has something to do with the power management).

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I experienced the same problem when logging in without power plug on a thinkpad with amd. I don't have a solution for the problem but i have a workaround:

Before logging in just switch to terminal with ctrl-alt-F2 then ctrl-alt-F7 and switch back with ctrl-alt-F1. If you login then the login doesn't freeze. Still not sure why it behaves so strangely.

Answer (score 0):

The first part of your problem is not related to power management. I think its more an issue with GDM. Try to re-install `gdm3` by:

`sudo apt install gdm3`

and then run:

`sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm3`

Regarding your issue for closing the lid and hibernation.

**Have you set up a swap ?**

If **no** then you need a swap partition for hibernation.

**My suggestion:**

Why don't you simply suspend the laptop when the lid is closed or if power saving is the goal then why not set it to poweroff. The boot speed with SSD is almost comparable to hibernation and you only loose a couple of seconds.

**To change the lid closed action follow the steps:**

1. `sudo nano /etc/systemd/logind.conf`
2. Find this line: `#HandleLidSwitch=suspend`
3. Uncomment it by deleting the `#`.
4. Save and Exit.
5. Then: `sudo systemctl restart systemd-logind.service`

Alternatively you can also set that line to `ignore`,`hibernate`,`poweroff`.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the feedback, I followed the steps but no luck. The screen just froze at login this morning.

Comment: I had the same problem with my Thinkpad when I was running Arch Linux with GDM3. My only solution at that time was to change to LightDm as my display manager and everything worked fine. Unfortunately I dont think you can change to lightDm on ubuntu18.04. Maybe someone can throw some light on that.

Comment: Hi, I tried to switch to lightdm but I encountered again the same issue tonight. I froze at the login prompt. I can only move the mouse cursor.

Answer (score 0):

Ah, so I was running into this, and then I thought "I bet 20.04 will fix it..." (it didn't). Searching around I saw some stuff on folks trying out `iommu=soft` for other boot issues and tried it (I also tried `nomodeset`, which fixed it but then other things got messed up). The `iommu=soft` fixed the issue with booting while on battery for me, you have to edit the grub file and add the `iommu=soft` to the `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT`.

1. `sudo vi /etc/grub/default`
2. Modify grub cmdline `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash iommu=soft"`
3. Update grub `sudo update-grub`

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/1032484)

Comment: @Pilot6 - Updated to look less like a question. I was running into the same issue and adding the `iommu=soft` fixed it for me on 20.04. Was not sure if it would work for 19.10, but thought it would be work recommending.